# SSIS package deployed to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, excel-interop, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that opens an Excel workbook, makes a bunch of edits and closes and saves. It uses a VB.NET script using Interop to achieve most of it and it runs fine from within VS. I have deployed this package to a SQL Server and it fails from SQL Server when I execute the package. SSIS and SQL Server are on the same server.

When I scale back the script to just a few edits then closes and saves, it runs fine from SQL Server. So I don't think it is permission related. It is almost like some Excel script commands work only in SSIS and not from SQL Server? I am a newbie to this and any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @mastashufu No error message, just says script failed, then I have go into task manager and manually kill the Excel process.

Comment: What is the account that runs the sql agent job? sql authentication or windows authentication? service account or User?

Comment: @Hadi Not even using SQL Agent, just manually executing the package from the IS Catalog within SQL.  The partial script uses the same data and saves it to the same place - so I don't think it is permissions.

Comment: Would some Excel.Interop commands only work from VS and not from within SQL???

Comment: @C-COOP i am not talking about permissions, Interop library need a normal user account to be able to open a workbook. If it is used by a service account *(example running dtexec using xp_cmdshell)* it will fails. It will just open an `EXCEL` process. Make sure you are running the package using a windows authentication. And it is good to provided the code used in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Interop library need a normal user account *(windows account)* to be able to open a workbook. If it is used by a service account *(example running dtexec using xp_cmdshell)* it will fails. It will just open an EXCEL process *(the Open method will return null)*. Make sure you are running the package using a windows authentication.

Also you can use [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql) command to execute the command using a windows account

Comment: OK - interesting.  But if it is opening the workbook, editing some cells and saving it would that not mean that the interop library is being used (in the shorter working script)?  I believe if I am executing the package manually it is passing my windows authentication to the package.  I need to use the jobstopwait function and that will not work with the EXECUTE AS.

Comment: @C-COOP just try to run the query using a windows account, and give a feedback. If it works we will search for a workaround for using `jobstopwait`

Comment: Same result, ran from query (so should have passed my Windows Authentication through).  Short script worked fine, longer script just never finishes and Excel process left sitting there.

Comment: What is the long script code? Also the short script?

Comment: You may have been correct all along...  instead of running the query straight up (assuming pass through authentication)  I tried running it with the EXEC AS using my same login information and I got this message:  Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 14
The server principal "DOMAIN\USERID" is not able to access the database "SSISDB" under the current security context.  Strange considering that account is DB admin.

Comment: Try assign sysadmin role to this windows account an run again

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2012/03/19/ssis-catalog-access-control-tips/

Comment: @C-COOP  anything New?

Comment: No - I am stuck.  I am going to have to read some more about the default security.  I am now getting "Cannot access the package or the package does not exist. Verify that the package exists and that the user has permissions to it."

Comment: @C-Coop i will try to give u more assistance, anyway hope that this answer putted you on the right way. Good Luck

Comment: @C-Coop after reading many articles EXECUTE AS will not solves the issue, stop trying to solve the issue using `EXECUTE AS`

Comment: Also read this article it may helps http://thinknook.com/execute-ssis-via-stored-procedure-ssis-2012-2012-08-13/

Comment: I have it now so the full script runs when I manually execute package from SQL, only fails when sent from a job.  So I am going to work on that now!  Likely permissions as you said.  Your help was excellent!

Comment: if you find this answer helpful just upvote it. Or accept it if it solved the issue

Comment: @C-COOP the best thing after letting other users to spend their time to give helps and at the end, to let them say `please up vote or accept` !! the best thing after getting help is to ignore other.

Comment: @C-COOP is everything going ok?

Comment: @Hadi Oh no - not ignoring anyone and appreciate the help!  Just not sure if the correct answer has been posted.  So now I have been able to create a proc that runs the SSIS package.  I can execute the procedure directly and it runs fine in around 2 minutes.  If I create a SQL Agent job just to run that proc - it comes back in 5 seconds and says success - but is unable to finish SSIS package.

Comment: I made myself owner of the job and am  a db_admin.  I get an error saying I am not able to access XXX database under this security context!

Comment: @C-COOP i am not the one who said that you ignored me, i know that you need to take your time testing and trying, before replying on SO

Comment: @C-COOP I always post `if you find this answer helpful just upvote it. Or accept it if it solved the issue`, because the user mostly forget to do that after that the issue is solved, or they find that the answer is helpful :)